# Iteration for iteration in a list

Tags: python, list, if-statement, python-3.6, nested-lists

Let's say I have 2 lists and a variable:

```
Name = "Siler City"
List1 = ["Frank", "Beth", "Jose" "Pieter"]
List2 = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Purple"]
```

This is a simple illustration of a complex problem and there is a reason I don't want to create a dictionary. These must be 2 separate list. What I want is to iterate through List1[0] and List2[0], etc... at the same time. So my desired results would be

> "The Red house is owned by Frank", "The Green house is owned by Beth",
>   "The Blue house is owned by Jose,"

etc...Why won't the below work and what is a better strategy?

```
for item in List1:
    if Name == "Siler City":
        for color in List2:
            print("The {} house is owned by {}".format(color, item))
```

Comment: You iterate through List2 for each item in List1 (because the second for loop is inside the body of the first for loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zip your lists together to iterate over both

```
for list1_elm, list2_elm in zip(List1, List2):
  pass # Remove pass when you add your print statement
  # Do things Here
```

Comment: @mad_ Thanks for the heads up! was trying to leave the rest up to OP but I can see how that might be confusing. Added in a place holder!

Comment: Note, it is *still* syntactically incorrect... you'd need a `pass` at least

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you! Adding a pass now

Comment: This code works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for item, color in zip(List1, List2):
    print("The {} house is owned by {}".format(color, item))
```

Comment: Disregard last comment. This is the most succinct answer. Thanks.